# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'/ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

Нужно открыть для чтения и записи файл Microsoft Word(.doc, .docx)
делал:

```
pip install docx
pip install python-docx
```

На обе эти команды получал следующую ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
```

Так же пробовал через сам PyCharm:

```
import docx
from docx import Document
```

Клацал на всплывающую ошибку для установки пакета непосредственно из PyCharm, получал такое:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

**вот сам код если нужно**

```py
from docx import Document


file = r'C:\Users\fsoci\Desktop\d.docx'#input('full path: ')

def getText(filename):
    doc = Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

print(getText(file))
```

Сколько не переустанавливал ни docx, ни python-docx, все равно были эти ошибки, в чем может быть проблема??

*Заранее спасибо!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows 10, python 3.7.3**

Убедитесь, что в настройках проекта интерпретатор стоит такой же как и тот, в который вы установили модули. Может такое быть, что при создании проекта было выбрано создание venv -- отдельная копия интерпретатора и если venv не активирована, глобальный pip установит в оригинальную папку питона, а venv останется неизмененным

---

Установка:

```
C:\Users\ipetrash> pip install docx                                                                                                                         
Collecting docx                                                                                                                                             
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/8e/5a01644697b03016de339ef444cfff28367f92984dc74eddaab1ed60eada/docx-0.2.4.tar.gz (54kB)           
     |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 491kB/s                                                                                                        
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\ipetrash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from docx) (4.3.4)                                                    
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=2.0 in c:\users\ipetrash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from docx) (6.1.0)                                             
Building wheels for collected packages: docx                                                                                                                
  Building wheel for docx (setup.py) ... done                                                                                                               
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\cc\8d\09\563edfd874a35c0c7ed129b6c4fa890efa4c26458bdec6ffc1                         
Successfully built docx                                                                                                                                     
Installing collected packages: docx                                                                                                                         
Successfully installed docx-0.2.4                                                                                                                           

C:\Users\ipetrash> pip install python-docx                                                                                                                  
Collecting python-docx                                                                                                                                      
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/83/c66a1934ed5ed8ab1dbb9931f1779079f8bca0f6bbc5793c06c4b5e7d671/python-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz (5.5MB)  
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.5MB 595kB/s                                                                                                       
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in c:\users\ipetrash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-docx) (4.3.4)                                      
Building wheels for collected packages: python-docx                                                                                                         
  Building wheel for python-docx (setup.py) ... done                                                                                                        
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\18\0b\a0\1dd62ff812c857c9e487f27d80d53d2b40531bec1acecfa47b                         
Successfully built python-docx                                                                                                                              
Installing collected packages: python-docx                                                                                                                  
Successfully installed python-docx-0.8.10
```

Проверка работы модуля:

```
C:\Users\ipetrash> python                                                                                                                                   
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32                                                        

Warning:                                                                                                                                                    
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has                                                                                  
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment                                                                              
please see https://conda.io/activation                                                                                                                      

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                      
>>> from docx import Document                                                                                                                               
>>> Document                                                                                                                                                
<function Document at 0x0000017E010D9378>                                                                                                                   
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня все работает:

```
pip install python-docx

D:\_Qt\__Qt>pip install python-docx
Collecting python-docx
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/83/c66a1934ed5ed8ab1dbb9931f1779079f8bca0f6bbc5793c06c4b
on-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz (5.5MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.5MB 437kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packa
thon-docx) (4.3.3)
Installing collected packages: python-docx
  Running setup.py install for python-docx ... done
Successfully installed python-docx-0.8.10
```

---

```
from docx import Document

symbols = {' ': ' ',
           'е': 'e',
           'у': 'y',
           'о': 'o',
           'з': '3',
           'р': 'p',
           'а': 'a',
           'х': 'x',
           'к': 'k',
           ',': '‚',
           '"': '”'}
# file = r'C:\Users\fsoci\Desktop\d.docx'#input('full path: ')
file = r'D:/_Qt/__Qt/d.docx'

def getText(filename):
    doc = Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)

    return '\n'.join(fullText)

print(getText(file))
```

---

```
D:\_Qt\__Qt>py aa.py
exec("self.labelList.append("+"self.X"+str(i)+")")


D:\_Qt\__Qt>
```

Comment: не знаю что это может быть, у половины рунета работает, у половины нет

Comment: @finally у меня сейчас Windows 7, Python 3.7, а у вас ?

Comment: десятка, питон как у вас